# Haproxy Forwarding Mail

Tags: sendmail, haproxy, mx-record

I have a bit of a problem in that I am trying to forward mail on through Haproxy but to entirely different servers.

The problem I am having is that there are multiple backends all going to different places and different sites. I am currently using the following listen configuration to do this however I know that hdr_sub(host) does not obtain the correct information for getting emails to their intended destination.

```
listen Mail_Handler
        mode                     tcp
        bind                     :25
        # Set timeouts
        timeout client          15s
        timeout connect         30s
        timeout server          30s
        rate-limit sessions     30

        ################## ACL Handlers ####################
        acl domain1.com hdr_sub(host) -i domain1.com
        acl domain2.com hdr_sub(host) -i domain2.com

        use_backend domain1.com if domain1.com
        use_backend domain2.com if domain2.com
```

So for example I have domain1.com and domain2.com and the MX record for domain1.com is

```
0 domain1.com
```

How is it possible to ensure that mail sent to the MX handler for domain1.com actually reaches domain1.com and the same with domain2.com. I am filtering the mail server too to prevent potential attackers obtaining the true IP

Is there any specific header I can use that will allow me to determine where the mail is destined for? Or any other way around doing this? If it is any benefit I am using Haproxy 1.4

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [configuration.txt](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt), when you use TCP mode..." no layer 7 examination will be performed." and hdr_sub is a layer 7 examination (7.5.3. Matching at Layer 7).

You can work only at level 4 and below (7.5.1. Matching at Layer 4 and below).